# Distinct value with same date in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

i have the table like this:

```
id    account_no  tax    date
1         201      10    2021-01-31
2         201      0     2021-01-31
3         301      20    2021-01-31
4         401      20    2020-10-10
```

i want the distinct value of `account_no` with having `tax <> 0` and `date = '2021-01-31'`

expected result:

```
account_no
201
301
```

how the query should i do?
im using visual studio 13.

im doing query:

```
Select distinct Account_No from ( 
Select Account_No, date, count(*) jumlah from table
Where date = '2021-01-31' and tax <> 0
Group By Account_No, date
Having count(*) > 1
) a
```

but the result keep showing distinct account_no with duplicate date

Comment: What have you attempt to do so far? Can you share some of your efforts?

Comment: Incidentally, I would have guessed that visual studio would be used in conjunction with mssql server

Comment: @FranciscodeCastro im edit the query

Comment: @hifanaya, the query is really simple as you described. There is already a valid answer

Answer (score 2):

It's quite straight forward (even syntax of the query is very similair to the description you gave..):

```
select distinct account_no from myTable
where tax <> 0 and date = '2021-01-31';
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me first explain you why your query will not work as expected and its analysis

```
Select distinct Account_No from ( 
    Select Account_No, date, count(*) jumlah from table
    Where date = '2021-01-31' and tax <> 0
    Group By Account_No, date
    Having count(*) > 1) a
```

- You are using having count(*)>1, this will discard the row with single occurrence
- Analysis :

1. You will first select all those records with date = '2021-01-31' and tax <> 0
2. You will group these records based on account no and date => and find count.
   This count do not give you any information you need for your result. You just want accounts

Optimal query is as suggested by @Michał Turczyn

```
select distinct account_no from myTable
where tax <> 0 and date = '2021-01-31';
```